# Why aren't results from database queries generally type safe?

Tags: java, oracle

When querying a database, why aren't the values returned as the same accurate Java types they were put in as? i.e. why aren't database query results generally type safe?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: I'd assume because the database's API can't deduce the expected Java type of the query results at compile time.

Comment: well, consider something like a `date`. there's a java date, and then there's the database date. maybe the DB date has a smaller allowable range of valid dates. e.g. java does -999,999 to +999,999 for years, while the db only does 1970->2038.

Comment: Because the database isn't written in Java, or designed for Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are speaking about is just a part of a bigger problem: **object-relational  [impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)**.

The short answer is that it's not always possible to safely convert database type to a corresponding Java type. For example, even integer type specifications don't always match between programming languages and databases (like, should be `int` 32-bit or 64-bit? Signed or unsigned?). The same goes for strings (ASCII or Unicode?). As @Marc B has already mentioned, things become even worse in case of more complex data types like `date`.